# PHP: Get each POST data from a text file and insert it to database

Tags: php, post, fopen

I have a hard time on how to get the POST data from the text file. I have this line of text from my text file:

> Wednesday October 11, 2017, 04:53 AM,reader_name=%22Impinj%20RFID%20Reader%22&mac_address=%2200%3a16%3a25%3a10%3a7E%3a85%22&line_ending=%0a&field_delim=%2c&field_names=antenna%5fport%2cepc%2cpeak%5frssi%2ctid&field_values=1%2c%22503030393839343834323200%22%2c%2d50%2c%22E280110520005756DE620231%22%0a1%2c%22000000000000001000000441%22%2c%2d53%2c%22E28011602000728E91750917%22%0a1%2c%2288000008%22%2c%2d60%2c%22E280116020007224B7650909%22%0a1%2c%22000000000000001000000441%22%2c%2d54%2c%22E28011602000728E91750917%22%0a1%2c%22503030393839343834323200%22%2c%2d48%2c%22E280110520005756DE620231%22%0a

the POST data are the following:
**reader_name, mac_address, line_ending, field_delim, field_names, and field_values**

I have created a code that will read a data from the text file but it failed:

```
<?php
$fn = "log.txt";
$read = readfile($fn);


// Store the POST variables.
$readerName = $_POST['reader_name'];
$macAddress = $_POST['mac_address'];
$lineEnding = $_POST['line_ending'];
$fieldDelim = $_POST['field_delim'];
$fieldNames = $_POST['field_names'];
$fieldValues = $_POST['field_values'];

//Connect to the database.
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '153624123', 'test') or die("Unable to select database");

// Replace the field delimiter with a comma.
str_replace($fieldDelim, ",", $fieldNames);

// Break the field values up into rows.
$rows = explode("\n", $fieldValues);

// Remove the last row. It's always blank
if (sizeof($rows))
    array_pop($rows);

$fieldNames = "reader_name,mac_address," . $fieldNames;

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $row = $readerName . "," . $macAddress . "," .
            $row;
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO tags ($fieldNames) VALUES ($row)");
    echo "INSERT INTO tags ($fieldNames) VALUES ($row)" . '<br />';
}
?>
```

I tried searching other ways in google but found no luck. the text file is from the RFID that we bought for our project which is called "speedway connect" product. it has a website and they posted their source code for HTTP POST. i followed everything but i got no luck.

https://support.impinj.com/hc/en-us/articles/202756148-HTTP-POST-with-Speedway-Connect-software-VIDEO-

Comment: Try `var_dump($_POST)` and paste the result

Comment: His not going to get any data because `$_POST` is empty. and from his text line there's a very big clean up to be done.

Comment: yes the POST is empty sir since it's from a text file. my problem here is how can i get the POST from my text file.

Comment: You can't get a POST by reading a text file. From top of my head you have `explode` the values `regex` to clean then assign that to your variable. And from the first look you have lot of identifying to do prior to clearing the data strings.

Comment: It's not post. You don't post it from a text file. You read it. Go back to the docs on readfile.

Comment: @Sand do you have a sample code sir?

Comment: you must first make sure that the form is sending the data with the correct type `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, then the file must be temporaly stored in `$_FILES`

Comment: @nosthertus my log is not from the form-data and i didn't upload a file as well. the log is from the RFID called "Speedway Connect". they have a source code on how to get HTTP POST.

link: https://support.impinj.com/hc/en-us/articles/202756148-HTTP-POST-with-Speedway-Connect-software-VIDEO-

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
$read = readfile($fn);
$string =urldecode(explode("^",$read)[1]);//or urldecode(preg_split('@(?=reader_name)@',$read)[1]); demo https://ideone.com/lfEn40
$post = [];
foreach (explode('&', $string) as $chunk) {
    $param = explode("=", $chunk); 
    $post[$param[0]] = isset($param[1])?$param[1]:'';      
}
$readerName = $post['mac_address'];
//....
```

change the following line in your file generator function

```
fwrite($fp, date("l F d, Y, h:i A") . "^" . $rawPostData . "\n"); 
//.....................................^ change here the coma into ^
```

Comment: nice, but his going to have lot of junk in his chunks :P.

Comment: thanks for the answer sir. but it didn't work though.

Comment: @madalinivascu i tried your new code but i got an error:

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\op\insert.php on line 9

Notice: Undefined index: reader_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\op\insert.php on line 11

Comment: @madalinivascu the updated code says: **Undefined index: reader_name**. still no luck.

Comment: you need to remove `date("l F d, Y, h:i A")` from your file generator or use a custom character to explode the string into the timestamp and the raw data, after that my code will work

Comment: @madalinivascu how? i got my code from the official website of the RFID that i bought from [impinj](https://support.impinj.com/hc/en-us/articles/202756148-HTTP-POST-with-Speedway-Connect-software-VIDEO-)

Comment: how what?how to remove the date or how to alter the string to add a custom character to explode your string?

Comment: see my updated answer, not the currently generate files will not work, you will need to manually change the coma into ^

Answer (score 0):

**$_POST** *is* set for:
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
In other words,  for **standard web forms**.

is your log file creating based on any form/post ?  if not then you don't get data from $_POST variable so you need to read data from file instead $_POST variable like @madalin say

Comment: I got the log from the RFID which is Speedway Connect. they have an open source code on how to get the POST data file.

here is the link: https://support.impinj.com/hc/en-us/articles/202756148-HTTP-POST-with-Speedway-Connect-software-VIDEO-